# Send void type defined function pointer as argument to be called

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments

I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible but it would be grate to be. It will really prove that C++ is a strong language.

So, I have a DLL and an EXE that uses a function exported by the DLL. That function takes an argument which is, or must be a pointer to another function, and executes it. Something like this:

```
extern void RunFunction(void (*FunctionPonter)()) {
    (*FunctionPonter)();
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
RunFunction(&FunctionToExecute);
```

The function sent as an argument will not have arguments, just a void function.

So, all this works, as it is presented here. Now, I would like to go further and define `(*void)()` as, for example, `Action`.

```
typedef (*void)() Action;

Action FunctionToExecute() {
    // My code. This function won't return results - void
}
```

and I would like to send the pointer to the function in my DLL like this:

```
// This is how it would be declared now in the DLL
extern void RunFunction(void (ACTION) {
    (*FunctionPonter)();
}

// and this is how I would like to use it
RunFunction(FunctionToExecute);
```

I am using VC2010 and I don't know how could I do that, if it is possible. Thanks for your ideas, explanations and help!

Comment: This starts off well, but then becomes completely unclear.  What do you want your second example to do, that your first example doesn't already do?

Comment: It's just to create a typedef for void (*)(), to differentiate it from other void functions that are not created to be sent as arguments. Just that!

Comment: C++ is indeed a strong language, if the *requirements* are clear and reasonable!

Comment: A typedef is not a new type, it's just an alias.  So a `void (*)()` and an `Action` are indistinguishable to the compiler.

Comment: Yes, but they help me know what is a function to be sent as parameters to other functions - I will call them Action functions - and what are just simple void functions to be called by other functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the proper syntax for function type `typedef` is

```
typedef void (*Action)();
```

Secondly, typedef-name for function type can be used to *declare* functions of that type, but they cannot be used to *define* such functions. I.e. if `FunctionToExecute` is the function you wat to execute through the pointer, then it has to be defined as

```
void FunctionToExecute() {
  /* whatever */
}
```

The calling function would be defined as

```
void RunFunction(ACTION p) {
  p();
}
```

And the call to it would look as follows

```
RunFunction(FunctionToExecute);
```

That's it. Unary `*` and `&` operators are optional with function pointers.

Comment: Thanks. That was my mistake, defining the function to be sent as the function typedef. Thanks to everybody!

Comment: "typedef-name for function types can be used to declare functions, but they cannot be used in function definitions." - that's too strict, as your own `void RunFunction(Action p) { } ` shows. That uses the typedef-name `Action` in the definition. Typedefs can be used in arguments or the return type, but a typedef can't be used as the complete type of a function in a definition. The root cause is that `Action FunctionToExecute()` defines a function that **returns** an `Action`, not a function that **is** an Action.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, that's just bad wording on my part. Meanwhile, I disagree with your "root cause". I'd say that the potential (invented) syntax for function definition through a typedef-name would look as `Action FunctioToExecute { /* body */ }`, i.e. no `()` after the name (consistent with the currently legal declaration syntax `Action FunctioToExecute;`). The real root cause, in my opinion, is the fact that parameter names cannot be supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to only allow certain functions to be passed as arguments to your DLL function.

Using a typedef won't work, as that just creates an alias; `Action` and `void (*)()` are indistinguishable to the compiler in your code.  Instead, you'll have to create a brand new type.  In C++, you should strongly consider using a [*functor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B):

```
// Abstract functor
struct Action {
    virtual void operator() () const = 0;
};

// The DLL function
void RunFunction(const Action &action) {
    action();
}

// Define your function as a derived functor
struct FunctionToExecute : Action {
    void operator() () const { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

// Run a function
RunFunction(FunctionToExecute());
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/5pl23.